# I am trying to incorporate firebase into my unity project but keep getting an error about my "Firebase.Crashlytics.Editor.dll"

Tags: ios, visual-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am trying to incorporate FireBase into my unity project but every time I try I get the error "Assembly 'Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Crashlytics.Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Google.JarResolver'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector."

So far I have tried deleting all of the files from FireBase and redownloading them I have also tried to start a new project and import the FireBase Packages into there.

I do not understand why this is happening. If this has happened​ to anyone else and they have managed to fix this problem can you please help me I am trying to make my first app for the iPhone and this has been the first error that I need help with so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P!

It looks like you're having a hard time finding the [Play Services Resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver). There are a few things you can try.

First, try to re-import Crashlytics and make sure you pull in the `PlayServicesResolver`:
[image: Import Play Services Resolver]

Second, if the dll is already imported. Select it in your project view, and make sure that it's set to be used in the Editor in your Inspector:
[image: Inspector screenshot]

Third, you can try downloading the unitypackage from the [repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) directly.

If none of these work, let us know what the host OS is (the one you use the Editor in) and your target OS (I assume Android, but I'd like to verify) for further debugging or reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.

--Patrick

Comment: I reimported and made sure it was checked and it seems to be working as of right now but I will keep you updated thank you

Answer (score 2):

This happen on Windows for Android build!

> Could not load signature Firebase.Crashlytics.Editor.iOSPostBuild
> Could not load file or assembly UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode
> Unloading broken assembly Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Crashlytics.Editor.dll

[image: error image]

To fix this:

1. Add **IOS** module via Unity Hub [add IOS module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A6Wr.png)
   [image]
2. Switch Unity to Ios build ( yes on PC/Windows ) and build it [make IOs build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvNU.png)
   [image]
3. Switch back to Android
4. Enjoy. No errors for Android build.

It's very strange, but it works!