# Unity Editor freezes for couple of seconds when hitting play - Firebase.Editor error

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am building an Android game and the problem is that any time I click Play in Unity editor, it has a delay of 6-10 seconds (and maybe more) at the very beginning (like freezing) every time I make a change and build the project which is very frustrating and time consuming (only in editor though, on Android devices it's fine). In this [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/639), it looks like there are more people having this problem. So, one suggestion was to remove `Google.IOSResolver_v1.2.156.dll` and it's `.meta` files from ExternalDependenceManager folder. I tried it and indeed it's loading much faster which clearly points out that there is a problem with **IOSResolver** in Unity Editor. Removing the files, bring me following errors:

1. Assembly 'Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Crashlytics.Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
   Reference has errors 'Firebase.Editor'.
2. Assembly 'Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
   Unable to resolve reference 'Google.IOSResolver'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
   Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

I can ignore them since they are not really causing any problems, but is there any other solution?

Maybe completely remove iOS Firebase plugin? I already installed only Android plugins though.

I checked also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540815/i-am-trying-to-incorporate-firebase-into-my-unity-project-but-keep-getting-an-er) but doesn't really helped me.

Note that I already tried with a completely empty project using Firebase causes the same problem.

### UPDATE

Installed the latest version of [EDM4U](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/raw/master/external-dependency-manager-latest.unitypackage) (external-dependency-manager) 1.2.157 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with AdMob earlier. Make sure the IOS plugin is installed by going into **Unity Hub -> Installs -> 3 dots on Unity version -> Add Modules** and select **iOS Build Support**. That fixed for me even though I don't develop for IOS.